# Insert data into Database gives conversion error

Tags: sql-server, mulesoft, anypoint-studio

I try to insert a data into a table but I found this error when I try to send:

> The conversion from UNKNOWN to UNKNOWN is unsupported.

Any suggestion? I followed the format but I'm not sure what I'm missing. This is my code:

```
     <ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message" doc:id="10959d07-3ebe-4634-aa37-1a2f3642deaf" >
            <ee:message >
                <ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload map (item, index) -> {
      QN_ID: item."QN ID",
      QN_Priority: item."QN Priority",
      QN_Maintenance_Order_ID: item."QN Maintenance Order ID"
    }]]></ee:set-payload>
            </ee:message>
        </ee:transform>
        <db:insert doc:name="Insert" doc:id="7c0547ba-ad67-40c1-8346-7f2cca05db63" config-ref="Database_Config">
            <db:sql ><![CDATA[INSERT INTO use_case_one(QN_ID, QN_Notification_Type, QN_Priority, QN_Priority_Text, QN_Priority_Type, Insert_At)
VALUES (:qnID, :qnPriority,:qnMain, '', '', '')]]></db:sql>
            <db:input-parameters ><![CDATA[#[{
    "qnID":payload.QN_ID,
    "qnPriority":payload.QN_Priority,
    "qnMain":payload.QN_Maintenance_Order_ID
}]]]></db:input-parameters>
        </db:insert>
```

Really appreciate any insight

Comment: Seems like a JDBC driver error. What are the data types of the three replacement parameters? (e.g.: are any of them arrays?)

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You should include inputs, versions of Mule runtime, Database connector, JDBC driver. Also you should provide the [complete error message](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough) instead of just a description.